# Can I verify the content of a Twitter Tweet through a callback?

Tags: javascript, twitter

I'm trying to integrate twitter into my site in a way that allows me to give a member of my site 'points' for tweeting about the site. Everything is working so far, except I can't figure out how to ensure that the user is actually saying something related to my site.

Basically, once the user submits a tweet, I would like to verify that the tweet contains my hashtag. The rest of the text can be whatever they like, but I don't want to give them points if they delete the hashtag from the tweet.

I'm using the javascript tweet button, and I put my code for assigning points inside of

twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) { ... });

How can I check what the user tweeted?

Thanks!

Comment: Even if you can do this, what if a user posts the tweet, gets the reward and then immediately deletes the tweet?

Comment: Yeah, there's not much that I can do about that